# Calculate the volume of the solid limited by surfaces

Tags: solid-geometry

Calculate the volume of the body limited by surfaces:
$$
z = 0\\
z = 8-2x-y\\
x^{2} +y^{2} = 4
$$

Have no idea how do it.

Comment: Please do not ask no-clue questions. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for advice on how to improve your question. Have you tried finding the bounds for $x,y,z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first quadrant
$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{0}^{8-2x-y}dxdydz$$